# Antd how to pass the getFieldDecorator to sub component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have used antd as react lib. And for form, I want to reuse some form fields and make those fields as sub component. In my example it's Address. My question is how to pass the getFieldDecorator to sub component Address, as  form property has been decorated by Form.create.

**antd version: 2.11.0**

**react version: 15.5.4**

Below is my example.

**Form component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Select } from 'antd';
import Address from '../common/Address'

const FormItem = Form.Item;

const formItemLayout = {
    labelCol: {
        xs: {span: 24},
        sm: {span: 6}
    },
    wrapperCol: {
        xs: {span: 24},
        sm: {span: 14}
    }
};

const Option = Select.Option;

class BaseForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(value) {
        console.log(`selected ${value}`);
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return(
            <Form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Address />
            </Form>
        )

    }
}
const CommonForm = Form.create()(BaseForm);
export default CommonForm;
```

**Address component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Select } from 'antd';

const FormItem = Form.Item;

const formItemLayout = {
    labelCol: {
        xs: {span: 24},
        sm: {span: 6}
    },
    wrapperCol: {
        xs: {span: 24},
        sm: {span: 14}
    }
};

const Option = Select.Option;



class Address extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(value) {
        console.log(`selected ${value}`);
    }

    render() {
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

        return (
            <div>
                <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Country" hasFeedback>
                        {getFieldDecorator('country', {
                            initialValue: 'US',
                            rules: [{required: true, message: 'Please input your country!'}]
                        })(
                            <Select style={{width: 150}} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                <Option value='US'>United States</Option>
                                <Option value='CA'>Canada</Option>
                            </Select>
                        )}
                </FormItem>

                <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="State" hasFeedback>
                        {getFieldDecorator('state', {
                            initialValue: 'CA',
                            rules: [{required: true, message: 'Please input your state!'}]
                        })(
                            <Select style={{width: 150}} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                <Option value='CA'>CA</Option>
                                <Option value='IA'>IA</Option>
                            </Select>
                        )}
                </FormItem>
                 </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Address;
```

Comment: Fixed by using <Address form={this.props.form}/>. Don't need to pass the property on Form component, just pass it to sub component.

Answer (score 6):

Just pass form to `Adress`

**Form component:**

```
class BaseForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {form} = this.props
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Address form={form}/>
      </Form>
    )

  }
}
const CommonForm = Form.create()(BaseForm)
export default CommonForm
```

**Address.jsx:**

```
const Address = ({form: {getFieldDecorator}}) =>
  <div>
    <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Country" hasFeedback>
      {getFieldDecorator(`country`, {
        initialValue: `US`,
        rules: [{required: true, message: `Please input your country!`}]
      })(
        <Select style={{width: 150}} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <Option value='US'>United States</Option>
          <Option value='CA'>Canada</Option>
        </Select>
      )}
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="State" hasFeedback>
      {getFieldDecorator(`state`, {
        initialValue: `CA`,
        rules: [{required: true, message: `Please input your state!`}]
      })(
        <Select style={{width: 150}} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <Option value='CA'>CA</Option>
          <Option value='IA'>IA</Option>
        </Select>
      )}
    </FormItem>
  </div>

export default Address
```