# Ant Radio button value didnt change value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Hi i am new to react and i am trying to add the radio button in my react app.
I am using the Ant Design for my radio button.

So now the problem is when i change the state of the button from Yes to No and then i go back and forth the value didn't change it show me the default value which is being set.

I am using the Redux to store the data into the react store and the changed value is getting updated in the react store.

so can any one help me with problem.

```js
state = {
  value: 1
};

radioChangeHandler = e => {
  this.setState({
    value: e.target.value
  });
};

<Form.Item>
  {getFieldDecorator("isBranchAvailable", {
    initialValue: this.props.branchDetails.isBranchAvailable
  })(
    <div>
      <label>Branch Available?</label>
      <br />
      <Radio.Group
        onChange={this.radioChangeHandler}
        defaultValue={this.state.value}
      >
        <Radio value={1}>yes</Radio>
        <Radio value={2}>no</Radio>
      </Radio.Group>
    </div>
  )}
</Form.Item>;

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    branchDetails: state.branchReducer.branch
  };
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it without AntDesign to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Try changing `defaultValue` with `value`.

Comment: @raibagul91 i tried but it is not working.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672052/antd-how-to-pass-the-getfielddecorator-to-sub-component

Answer (score 3):

The getFieldDecorator needs more information about the inputs you are inserting. For me I only had to specify an answer value type to make it worked.

```
<Form.Item>
  {getFieldDecorator("isBranchAvailable", {
    rules: [{ required: false }], //Always set this property for precautions even if it's false
    initialValue: this.props.branchDetails.isBranchAvailable,
    valuePropName: 'checked' //INSERT ANSWER TYPE DEFINITION HERE
  })(
    <div>
      <label>Branch Available?</label>
      <br />
      <Radio.Group
        onChange={this.radioChangeHandler}
        defaultValue={this.state.value}
      >
        <Radio value={1}>yes</Radio>
        <Radio value={2}>no</Radio>
      </Radio.Group>
    </div>
  )}
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Changing the value of the `Radio`s to a proper value `{1}` (instead of a hardcoded string) did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use`<Radio.Group onChange={this.radioChangeHandler} defaultValue={this.state.value} value={this.state.value}>`

Comment: Why both defaultValue & value?

Comment: defaultValue is used to load the default value on the first render. After that, for every updates, the value present in 'value' attribute is considered.

Comment: Is it? I don't think so. `defaultValue` is used when we don't have `onChange` handler.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but in the documentation of antD the defaultValue property shows 'Default selected value'.

Comment: @Bimalendu I have tried as per your suggestion but it didn't work in that way. Now also it take the default value even after changing the state

Comment: With AntDesign, using Forms, you should not use Value or Default value of the component it self. Instead use the initialValue prop of the Form.Item component.